# get_posts changes main query

Tags: loop

Here is my code in single.php :

```
<?php if (have_posts()):the_post() ?>
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3> <!-- Prints `Hello World` -->
    <?php if (!empty($someOtherPosts = get_posts(['posts_per_page' => 3]))): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($someOtherPosts as $post): ?>
                <li><?php echo $post->post_title ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3> <!-- Prints `Bye World` -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Why am I getting different title in the next *the_title()* call and how can I manage this?

Comment: Have you written `global $post` anywhere else in your template?

Comment: no I haven't. If you put the piece of code in single.php you probably get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_posts()` isn't modifying the main query. The problem is that you're overwriting the global `$post` variable in your `foreach` loop. I guess if you're in a template then you're in the same scope as the global variable and don't need to specify `global $post;` for this to happen (as you would if you were inside a function). Rename `$post` in your loop and the issue will go away:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):the_post() ?>
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
    <?php if (!empty($someOtherPosts = get_posts(['posts_per_page' => 4]))): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($someOtherPosts as $someOtherPost): ?>
                <li><?php echo $someOtherPost->post_title ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```